# Ruby Rails set true on specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to update boolean to false (reset to false) when time reaches midnight, lets say 11:59pm?

I have a this:

```
t.boolean "status", :default => false
```

so when user clicks and updates the status to true, using this: `@user.update_attribute(:status, true)` but i want to make it false on next day, possible ? thanks

Comment: Use a cronjob to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00 00 * * * ruby path/to/your/midnight_script.sh

```
# midnight_script.sh
echo 'update "posts" set status = 'false' WHERE status = 'true';' | su - postgres -c "psql MYDBNAME"
```